# Android studio file not found exception

Tags: android

I created a custom video camera application with camera API I also created a URI for the recorded video and created a storage path. After storing I tried to upload the video to a PHP server using the URI I created but I keep getting an error on the logcat:

> fileNotFoundException:
>
> file does not exist:\storage\emulated\pictures\videocal\new_20171110_092345.mp4
>
> no directory found

I was wondering, if the logcat says file does not exist, why does it show my the directory and file name? I also checked to see if I could find the file on my phone and the file was in the exact same directory as the logcat has shown.

Comment: Have you added : READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in permission?

Comment: it will be good if you show the code also.

Comment: And you probably also need WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE to write that file to the location.

Comment: I only added the write permission. I say in a tutorial that just by enabling the write permission the read permission will automatically be enabled